# how to create a submit button on symfony who get from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am new to php symfony.
Does someone know how to create a submit button, which takes a data from Mysql?
it works, but redirect me to another twig and i think is a little confused.

```
public function newAction(Request $request)   {

    $b = new Bank();

    $for = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $b);

    $for->handleRequest($request);

    if($for->isSubmitted() && $for->isValid()){

        $bank = new Bank();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Bank::class)->findAll();
        return $this->render('f/select.html.twig',[
                      'key'=>$em
                    ]);
    }
    return $this->render('f/sess.html.twig',['formed'=>$for->createView()]);  
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Explain a little bit more what is your Goal or what do you want to do because from what you asked and what you wrote it not clear what the problem is

Comment: i just want to create a submit button , and when he is clicked to create a query which query selects data from Mysql. But i don't want to create it with class